# Have a MessageBox Confirmation Work as a Submit Button

Tags: html, coldfusion

Instead of a submit button, I want the "ok" button on a MessageBox to work as a submit button. This is something I'm trying to accomplish in ColdFusion.

Here's an example only showing the vital code. Basically if a user hits "no", nothing will happen, but if a user hits "yes" it should register as a submit button. I have gone through tutorials and a ColdFusion book, and can't seem to find an example of what I'm looking for.

I'm aware it is something to do with the callbackhandler.

```
<HTML>
<Head>
    <script  type="text/javascript"> 

        //Function to show results of other message boxes. 
        var showResult2 = function(btn){} 

        //The button onClick handler displays the message boxes. 
        function showMB(mbox)  { 
            ColdFusion.MessageBox.show(mbox); 
        } 
    </script> 
</Head>
<Body>

    <cfform action="PlatinumTest.cfm" method="post">


    <cfinput name="Comfirmation" type="Submit" value="Submit" 
            onclick="showMB('mymessagebox02')"> 


    <cfmessagebox name="mymessagebox02" type="confirm"  
            message="Are you sure you want to submit?"  
            labelNO="No" labelYES="Yes"  
            callbackhandler="showResult2"/> 

</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You need to give your CFFORM an ID. Then in your showResult2, you can just document.getElementById("myForm").submit();. At the very least, fire off a JavaScript alert() in showResult2 to make sure the callbackhandler is firing that function.

Comment: by changing the cfinput type from submit to button and following your advice plus adding an if statement for yes and know I have the function working. I do have another question however. Since the object isn't a submit button my error messages for empty testbox objects no longer pop up. For example I have a textbox with this code `<CFinput type="text" required="yes">`. Is there away to still have my warning messages for these objects?

Comment: Why not do a simple jquery alert box?

Comment: Ok how would I do that? Sorry I'm unskilled with java/coldfusion. I'm willing to try.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do form validation. I find that http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ is very similar to ColdFusion's `<cfform>` approach.

Comment: First, stop using the ColdFusion UI components. They will cause you issues down the road. Your best bet, as has been pointed out, is to use another library, jQueryUI, for example. The documentation for jQueryUI is pretty good and they have lots of sample code for all the components.

Answer (score 2):

As Scott said DO NOT USE COLDFUSIONUI! I put that in caps because as ColdFusion updates those UI library may become unstable over time. Also, you would need to add CFIDE as a virtual directory which I don't like myself.

Your best bet is to simply use JQueryUI for this. It's very simple and easy to do. I will give you an example but I would like for you to try your own code. I'd rather you get it yourself and learn.

```
<HTML>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
               $("body").on('click','#formSubmit',function(e){
                   e.preventDefault();
                   var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
                   if (answer){
                       $("#formTest").submit();
                   } else {
                       return false;
                   }
               });
            });
       </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="action_page.cfm" method="POST" id="formTest">
            <input name="formSubmit" type="Submit" value="Submit" id="formSubmit">
       </form>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there away it will not bypass the "Required" attributes in textboxes?

Comment: Simply add an if/else statement using jQuery validationUI or make your own function where the function submits the form. I'll update the code I posted whenever I get go my PC.

Comment: I finally found a tutorial to show me how to program cold fusion better. I have to informally learned Cold Fusion for a project I have to program. I finally found a decent trainer. Instead of popping a messagebox I'm having the page reference itself once, popping a label on the page. Then after the user hits the dynamically imputed "yes" button, the user is then taken to the submission page.

Comment: According to your question this is still the best answer. Please accept it.